# Approximate polygon with multiple circles

Tags: geojson, geo

Background : I need to make Google Ads campaigns that targets a polygon region. I receive this region (which is actually an area where people can access quickly through a way of transportation (e.g : car) a facility we are making a campaign for). Google ads having dropped support for targeting a polygon area we can really only target a group of circles.

So I thought about approximating the polygon with circles (which would be in my understanding "incircle", or "inscribed" circles of this polygon).

[image: Example]

A quick and not perfect example, an algorithm would cover as much polygon (the green area) as possible with possibly a parameter to control the maximum number of circles to do so

I found only information about approximating a polygon that is very close to a circle with a single circle, I need multiple ones tho.

Is there any therorical algorithm/any implementation of it, any package or am I mistaken about the idea I have to resolve my challenge about Google Ads geo targeting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found (who took me 2 days to fully implement) is to create with turfjs a bounding box around my polygon then create a grid of squares (turf.squareGrid) then turn it into a matrix full with either 0 or information about a square. Then a recursive function find the biggest square in this matrix, then the next one etc. until all squares are into equivalent or bigger squares. Then I made circles around these bigger squares (with radius being equal to `sqrt(2) (~1.41) * (perimeterOfABigSquare / 2)`.